# Check result from grep of apt-get and use in bash conditional

Tags: linux, bash

I am trying to test for information about a specific package version on Debian. However, my grep against the result from APT doesn't seem to be doing anything. I'm not sure how to write the bash command:

```
if [[ $(apt-get -s install golang | grep "E: Unable to locate") ]]; then        
    echo "problem"
    exit;
fi

if apt-get -s install golang | grep "E: Unable to locate" > /dev/null; then     
    echo "problem"
    exit;
fi

OUTPUT=`apt-get -s install golang | grep --quiet "E: Unable to locate"`
if [ -n "$OUTPUT" ]; then
    echo "problem"
    exit;
fi
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? What do you expect to get?

Comment: If the grep matches, then I know there is a problem locating the package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The message, like most error messages, is printed on stderr. You can redirect stderr to stdout:

```
if [[ $(apt-get -s install golang 2>&1 | grep "E: Unable to locate") ]]; then
```

However, the better way of doing this is:

```
if ! apt-get -s install golang > /dev/null
then
  echo "problem"
  exit 1
fi
```

You can optionally use `> /dev/null 2>&1` if you want the user's only error message to be "problem".